Why is it so common to use the dbContext directly in the controller in a WebApi application?
Actually, in a Web API application using Entity Core, it seems very common to inject the application context to the controllers, so the controllers use directly the dbContext to do its work.
Something like this:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ActorDTO>>> GetAsync()
{
    return await _contextConsultas.Actores.ToListAsync();
}

But I have some disavantages with this solution.
One is that what happen if I want to use a new version of entity core. Sometimes there are some breaking updates that modify the behavior of entity core. Perhaps how it is work an include or any other functionality. In this case, the controller has to know the implementation and the behaviour of entity core, and I should to modify all the endpoints in all the controllers.
If the controller would use a repository, and interface that is implemented by class, the controller doesn't need to know the implementation, so if in the future I want to use another version that implements the interface, I can use it and the controller is not needed to be modify.
The code would be something like that:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ActorDTO>>> GetAsync()
{
    return await _applicationContex.GetAllActorsAsync();
}

Later, in the main project, if I am using dependency injection, I only need to chage the implementation that I want to use.
But seeing many examples in which the controller uses the dbContext directly, I am wondering if nowdays it is still as useful as I think to wrap the dbContext in a repository.
Thanks.


In online documentation, everything is oversimplified because of space constraints. 2) Because what matters overall is not how does the controller need to change, but how much needs to be changed in the application overall. If your controller methods are simple data access, and don't have much in the form of an underlying data model, then it is likely that any change to the EF core interface would require as much work changing a repository vs controllers. You don't reduce the work, only move it, unless you can come up with an abstraction shared by multiple endpoints.


@user1937198: That looks like an answer. Can you copy it over to the answer box?

One is that what happen if I want to use a new version of entity core. Sometimes there are some breaking updates that modify the behavior of entity core Interfaces are always nice to use, especially for mail, document generation, and all such things. Makes it easier to test. But I mean, what you're describing is just moving the problem of updating from one place to another

I think there are two reasons

Entity Framework. EF was intended to be used this way. It makes it "easy" to spin up the old style MVC razor webpages and apis. It does all your DB stuff for you and the controller builds the view so you have a simple three layer application, "out of the box".

Microservice Architecture/Backend For Frontend. If you have a small API but implement a service layer, models, a data layer, entities and DTOs then you have a LOT of code which is really only needed for larger more complex projects. In your small project its just duplicated structs and wrapped empty layers. There is a strong argument to just drop it all and do one liner controller methods.



I am wondering if nowdays it is still as useful as I think to wrap the
dbContext in a repository.

EF and the repository pattern don't mix well. Wrapping your context in a repository does separate your layers, but arguably you are better off not using EF, or try to bind directly to your Business Models with fluent setup rather than having separate Entities with attributes.
Also, I notice you have DTOs in your example. But if your models are anemic structs you can just return them from the controller directly, with no DTO required.
Compare
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ActorDTO>>> GetAsync()
{
    return await _applicationContex.GetAllActorsAsync().ToDTOs();
}

AppContext
{
    GetAllActorsAsync() { return _contextConsultas.GetAllActorsAsync() }
}


ActorDTO
{
   ...
}

Actor
{   
   ...
}

ActorEntity
{   
   ...
}

With
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Actor>> GetAllActors()
{
    return await _contextConsultas.GetAllActorsAsync();
}

Actor
{   
   ...
}


Thanks for the answer. I understand for small projects it could be over engineering, but if in the future I want to update to a new version of entity core, that perhaps changes methods, or change behaviour of some methods, that has passed in the past. Wouldn't it too much work change the code of all controllers and check if it works? If I implement a new repository that I test that it works as the controllers expect, wouldn't it better?

And a second question. If I would like to use projections for example, or another more advanced feature of EF, that it is possible to need also in small projects. All this code, would it have to be implemented in the controller? If this is the case, the controller becomes more complex.

@ÁlvaroGarcía Consider how much work it would be to update the repository, vs update the controllers. Just because you have a repository doesn't mean you magically don't have to update anything. If you haven't significantly decreased the total amount of change, and change is unlikely (EF core is mostly backwards compatible, baring swapping out the ORM completely), then you aren't actually likely to save much work overall, even if you reduce the change needed to the controllers. And that isn't worth the upfront cost.

@ÁlvaroGarcía As for projections, a certain level of complexity in a controller is not a bad thing. Either buisness logic or data access. But you don't usually want both. So if you don't have much buisness logic then more complex data access becomes viable. If you have non-trivial data access and non-trivial buisness logic in a non-trivial number of your endpoints, thats when you are starting to get into 'more complex projects'.

If you have a large monolith style program or desktop app, then you can see how layer separation and interface segregation help you with refactoring. But only because each layer does multiple things. With the case of most REST APIs a single controller method is called, does one thing and then exits. If you need to change that thing you can just change it. Extra layers dont help


so many up votes for simplifying and removing layers when transitioning to micro or web services. You already have the 7-layer OSI network model in between services. How many layers does a person really need?

